# Aframe Multiple Pattern Ratio

Tags: javascript, web, aframe, artoolkit, ar.js

Hello I want To Use Multiple Patterns With Different Ratio . Can Any One Help Me to Sort Out This . I Can Use Use Multiple Markers With Different Ratio But I Am Not Able To Use Multiple Markers With Dirrerent Ration .

Like
Pattern One (Hiro) - HIRO ( Which has ratio of 0.50 by default),

Pattern Two (Custom QR Code) With Ratio 0.75 - PATTERN,

```
Tag <a-scene arjs="patternRatio: 0.75">
<a-marker type="pattern" preset="hiro" vidhandler="target: #vid1">
--------
<a-marker
        type="pattern"
        url="https://cdn.glitch.com/e85b316e-eed9-4e96-814e-d12630bc00df%2Fpattern-qr-code.patt?v=1577440081157"
        vidhandler="target: #vid2"
      >
```

Glitch : [Multi Pattern Code](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/aframe-multi-pattern-multi-pattern-ratio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that actually it is not possible, because is not implemented. You could add as you did `patternRatio` to the `<a-scene>` but this will add the same patternRatio to all markers in the scene. You could add PatternRatio to the a-marker component inside the [component-anchor.js](https://github.com/kalwalt/AR.js-org/blob/master/aframe/src/component-anchor.js) in this way:

```
// FIXME
AFRAME.registerPrimitive('a-marker', AFRAME.utils.extendDeep({}, AFRAME.primitives.getMeshMixin(), {
    defaultComponents: {
        'arjs-anchor': {},
        'arjs-hit-testing': {},
    },
    mappings: {
        'type': 'arjs-anchor.type',
        'size': 'arjs-anchor.size',
        'url': 'arjs-anchor.patternUrl',
        'patternRatio': 'arjs-anchor.patternRatio', // add this line !
        'value': 'arjs-anchor.barcodeValue',
        'preset': 'arjs-anchor.preset',
        'min-confidence': 'arjs-anchor.minConfidence',
        'marker-helpers': 'arjs-anchor.markerhelpers',
        'smooth': 'arjs-anchor.smooth',
        'smooth-count': 'arjs-anchor.smoothCount',
        'smooth-tolerance': 'arjs-anchor.smoothTolerance',
        'smooth-threshold': 'arjs-anchor.smoothThreshold',

        'hit-testing-render-debug': 'arjs-hit-testing.renderDebug',
        'hit-testing-enabled': 'arjs-hit-testing.enabled',
    }
}))
```

you should rebuild the lib before using, run: `npm install` and then `npm run build` in the main AR.js folder. I have not tested the code so i can not sure that this code works. BTW it will be nice to add such a feature...